# How to add color to surface pattern of materials in revit api c#

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am working on a project where I am required to add properties to the materials of an element in revit api
I was able to do the task except I could not add the surface pattern color and cut pattern color.

My code is as follows

```
Color matColor = new Color(Byte.Parse(materials.Red.ToString()), Byte.Parse(materials.Green.ToString()), Byte.Parse(materials.Blue.ToString()));
myMaterial.Color = matColor;
myMaterial.Transparency = 0;
myMaterial.SurfacePatternColor = matColor;
myMaterial.CutPatternColor = matColor;
```

Color is applied only to materials color and not to the surface pattern and cut pattern
Also I do not get any errors
Please guide me as to where I am going wrong

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think it does apply the color, but you forgot to add a pattern. So you now have a color but an empty pattern.
Do you want it to be solid? Then I think the following code should work (I have not tested it):

```
FillPatternElement myFillPattern = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(FillPatternElement)).Cast<FillPatternElement>().First(a => a.Name.Contains("Solid fill"));
myMaterial.SurfacePatternId = myFillPattern.Id;
myMaterial.CutPatternId = myFillPattern.Id;
```